# How do I deal with old collected metrics in Prometheus?

Tags: metrics, prometheus

I am using a Gauge Vector in my application for collecting and exposing a particular metric with labels from my application in the Prometheus metrics format. The problem is that once I have set a metric value for a particular set of labels, even if that metric is not collected again it will be scraped by Prometheus until the application restarts and the metric is removed from memory. This means that even if that metric is no longer valid anymore (hasn't been set again for a day say) Prometheus will still be scraping it as if it's a fresh metric.

Is it possible to either set an expiry time for collected metrics or to remove the collected metric completely? Or are problems like this dealt with on the Prometheus server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the correct semantics. Prometheus deals with metrics and metrics don't go away just because they haven't changed in a while. What you should be doing is keeping the gauge up to date.

It sounds like you might want a logs-based monitoring system, such as provided by the ELK stack.